# Wheel off turbo trainer vs nut axle

Tags: cassette, axle, bolt, wahoo

I am looking at buying a wahoo kickr v5 wheel off trainer.

The bike I have is a falcon grand tour. It is a 3x7 cassette which I understand well take washers to make work, no problem.

The problem I am not sure about is the axel is a oldskool bolt version. This bike will solely be used in the trainer so can I not just use a qr bolt?. Do I need to convert it as I will be not suing any of the wheel that's currently attached (I will be buying a new 7 speed cassette).

The dropouts are 130mm.

Sorry for the long, awkward question. I have no idea what I am doing!

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

If you have a solid axle on your rear hub, you cannot use a quick release unless you replace the axle with a hollow one: the quick-release skewer goes through the axle.

However, if the bike will be living on the trainer full-time, I don't see any reason to bother. You can bolt the bike on and leave it be.

Comment: Thanks so much for the quick reply, that is exactly what I was thinking.